# validate date format in columns with other columns VBA

Tags: vba

if column F is in this date format then column K should have this code CD else error msg box my code is below does not seem to work for different date format setting in that column pls help

```
Sub date_check3()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")
Dim lr As Long, Target As Range

lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Target In ws.Range("F2:F3" & lr & ",K2:K3" & lr)
    If Target.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM" And Target.Offset(0, 5) <> "CD" And Target <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Error" & Target.Address
    End If
Next Target

End Sub
```

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. Can you show examples where this fails? Are you testing for that ***specific*** date format OR do you just want to know if the cell is formatted as ***ANY*** date?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "does not seem to work for different date format setting"?

Your condition asks for a specific format: Target.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"

To check if the value in a cell looks like a date in an arbitrary format, you could use following line:

```
If IsDate(Target) And Target.Offset(0, 5) <> "CD" And Target <> "" Then
```

Comment: files are in that format in my code but for some reason its does not seem to pick up, when i click or copy the cell it removes the first digit of the month not sure if that the root cause

Answer (score 0):

You loop range is wrong. You just need to loop through one column. Also, since you are looping through `Column F`, you should update your `lr` calculation to check that columns range.

```
lr = ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).ROw

For Each Target In ws.Range("F2:F" & lr)
```

---

*+ last row worksheet reference updating*

Comment: the issue is when i have file that has special or custom format date values macro is not picking up

Comment: So document those formats and check for them too

Comment: files are in that format in my code but for some reason its does not seem to pick up, when i click or copy the cell it removes the first digit of the month not sure if that the root cause